# External access to view elements created with createController and added to another view

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I have a problem. 
There is a view **row.xml**

```
<Alloy>
     <View>
         <Switch id = "search_switch" bindId = "search_switch" />
         <Label id = "search_switch_label" />
     </ View>
</Alloy>
```

And MAIN view

```
<View id = "general" bindId = "general ">
  <Label id = "testLabel" />
</View>
```

When I adding

```
var control = Alloy.createController ('row');
Control.search_switch_label.text = 'TEST';
$.parent.add (control.getView());
```

All is perfectly added, **but how to access the methods and properties of search_switch?**

$.search_switch - says that **"undefined"!!!**

$.testLabel.text = '1234567890'; - All OK!

Answer (score 0):

In your **main view** if you are trying to get the methods of `row.xml`, then you have two basic ways to do that :

> 1) Using the exports (in `row.js`)

```
var init = function (){
    // some code here
}

exports.getInit = init;
```

> 2) Using the Alloy.Globals (in `row.js`)

```
Alloy.Globals.init = function(){
    // some code here
}
```

Now to access the init function in Main View, you'll have to do the following respectively :

> 1) access exports function (in `MainView.js`)

```
var control = Alloy.createController ('row');
control.getInit();
```

> 2) access Alloy.Globals function (in `MainView.js`)

```
var control = Alloy.createController ('row');

if(Alloy.Globals.init)
    Alloy.Globals.init();
```

**Good Luck & Cheers**

Answer (score 0):

Firs thing as per your code is that when you use $, it means you are accessing the controls of the current controller so you can not use other controller's controls just by using $ sign. In your case, you need to set reference in you row.js file so you can access that controls or any variable or function in other controllers.

You need to do same as you did for search_switch_label. You can access search_switch object by control object in main.js like

```
control.search_switch.value
```